# Пространства имён

Tags: php

Почему не работает ни один файл, я никак понять не могу?

```
<?php

namespace Lev{
    const MyConst = 'MyValue';
}

namespace Lev\MyClasses{
    class MyClass{
        public $a = 1;
        public function MyMethod(){
            echo 'Hello';
        }
    }
}

class MyClass{
    public $a = 5;
}

$a = new Lev\MyClasses\MyClass();
$b = new MyClass();

echo $a->a;
echo $b->a;
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
<?php
namespace PHP7\functions;
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function debug($obj){
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($obj);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo $obj->getTitle();
}

namespace PHP7\classes;

class Page{
    protected $title;
    protected $content;

    public function __construct($title = '', $content = ''){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }
}

$page = new PHP7\classes\Page('Контакты', 'Содержимое страницы');

PHP7\functions\debug($page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php довольно информативные сообщения об ошибках.

> Fatal error: No code may exist outside of namespace {} in /in/NMepG on line 16

Часть кода в первом файле вне какого либо пространства имён.
Необходимо его указать, хотя бы анонимный.

```
<?php

namespace Lev{
    const MyConst = 'MyValue';
}

namespace Lev\MyClasses{
    class MyClass{
        public $a = 1;
        public function MyMethod(){
            echo 'Hello';
        }
    }
}

namespace {
    class MyClass{
        public $a = 5;
    }

    $a = new Lev\MyClasses\MyClass();
    $b = new MyClass();

    echo $a->a; // 1
    echo $b->a; // 5
}
```

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP7\classes\PHP7\classes\Page' not found

Сразу понятно, что подобное указание имени класса интерпретируется относительно текущего пространства имён.
Можно, например, добавить первый слеш, чтобы отталкиваться от корневого:

```
$page = new \PHP7\classes\Page('Контакты', 'Содержимое страницы');

\PHP7\functions\debug($page);
```

Comment: Спасибо, только я не понимаю, зачем создание класса и вывод его вкладывать во внутрь namespace?

Comment: Таков синтаксис пространств имён. Вообще, желательно не смешивать объявления классов и исполняемый клиентский код в одном файле. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php

Comment: Этот синтаксис был разработан исключительно для возможности объединить много файлов в один для оптимизации, перед деплоем. При разработке желательно придерживаться PSR-0/4 совместимых соглашений...

Comment: то есть, без первого слеша, он будет искать вне файла?

Comment: Вне файла он будет искать только если инициализирован автозагрузчик. Без слеша он будет искать класс `\Текущий\неймспейс\Указанный\неймспейс\Класс`, что видно в сообщении об ошибке.